# Unable to retrieve the month from date parameter using vba function in mdx

Tags: sql, oracle, mdx, msdn, mdxstudio

I am trying to retrieve month from parametrized date , by using :

```
 vba!month(${parDate}) or

 vba!datePart(m,${parDate}) or

 vba!format(${parDate},'mmm')
```

None of the above is working.Can you guide, what is the right approach to do this?

Comment: can any one tell me what i m doing wrong ?

Comment: What environment are you working in? What language? This does not look like MDX statements, neither like SQL statements, just like some code fragments from whatever. Could you give a sample what may be contained in variable `parDate`?

Comment: I think in relation to this question this is a complete answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510163.aspx What is the context of your snippets?

Comment: Where does Oracle come into play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(try uppercase 'MM' rather than 'mmm' - even 'mm' is wrong as it will look for minutes rather than months)

This question and answer looks at working with dates:
[Changing a date format to a shorter date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815369/changing-a-date-format-to-a-shorter-date)

MSDN is a good reference for the available `vba` functions in `mdx` that you can use to play around with dates. Current link is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510163.aspx

I'm assuming you have a date dimension and would like to create a calculated measure that returns a numeric value that is the month.
Using `AdWks` I can do the following:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DateValue] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DateKey] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DateMONTH] AS 
    Mid
    (
      [Measures].[DateKey]
     ,5
     ,2
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[DateValue]
   ,[Measures].[DateKey]
,[Measures].[DateMONTH]
  } ON 0
 ,Order
  (
    {
      Exists
      (
        [Date].[Date].MEMBERS
       ,[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2010]
      )
    }
   ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.MemberValue
   ,BDESC
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

But maybe you'd just like to play around with today's date and extract the month:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[DateValue] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
  MEMBER [Measures].[TodayKey] AS 
    format(Now(),'yyyMMdd')
  MEMBER [Measures].[TodayMONTH] AS 
    Mid
    (
      [Measures].[TodayKey]
     ,5
     ,2
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[DateValue]
   ,[Measures].[TodayKey]
,[Measures].[TodayMONTH]
  } ON 0
 ,Order
  (
    {
      Exists
      (
        [Date].[Date].MEMBERS
       ,[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2010]
      )
    }
   ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.MemberValue
   ,BDESC
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: @ whytheq: It's working fine ..thanks a lot for your quick response

Comment: @ whytheq:sorry for delay reply